# error while installing tensorflow in conda environment (CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist.)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

trying to install tensorflow using conda package manager
using following command

> conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

but it gives following error while executing transaction

> CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist.
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run `conda clean --all --yes` and `conda update anaconda`.

Do you have a `conda.exe` file in the following folder `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\`?

Do you use the latest Conda?

Another solution could be to create a conda environments `conda create -n name_environment pip python=3.5` and using pip to install tensorflow `pip install tensorflow` inside the new environment 
after having activated it (`activate name_environment`).

P.S. I can not write a comment because I do not have enough reputation.
EDIT - Now i can!

Comment: thanks ... tried running conda clean an updated conda but still facing the same problem... I am able to install other libraries but having the problem with this one.  ... worked by creating another environment

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7713

You could try to use `conda config --add pinned_packages defaults::conda`
You should use that if you have conda from defaults instead of conda-forge and want to make sure it stays that way.


Otherwise, to help you, I/we need more information about your environment

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and

```
conda update -n root conda
```

Solved the problem. The env name "root" is for conda <= 4.3, otherwise use:

```
conda update -n base conda
```

I hope this helps.